# R plot points at irregular dates

Tags: r, date, plot, points

I am trying to plot a graph of fund prices at irregular dates.

E.g.

```
salpr = c(1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 2, 5, 7, 9)
         # yyyy-mm-dd
saldt = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-14", "2015-02-01",
          "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01" )
dd = data.frame(saldt,salpr)
```

Here is my effort ...

```
with(dd, plot(saldt, salpr, xaxt="s"))

axis.Date(1, at=seq(min(as.Date(dd$saldt)), max(as.Date(dd$saldt)), by="months"), format="%m-%Y")
text(dd$saldt, dd$salpr+0.5,dd$salpr)
```

I want to use plot as I've don't have access to ggplot on my controlled environment.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: managing dates in R is kinda tricky for starters. this Eric Zivot's document can help you https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/Working%20with%20Time%20Series%20Data%20in%20R.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple code as below seems to do what you are after (?)

```
salpr = c(1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 2, 5, 7, 9)
# yyyy-mm-dd
saldt <- as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-14", "2015-02-01",
          "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01" ))
dd <- data.frame(saldt,salpr)
```

[image]